# create pjax form inside a active form yii2

Tags: php, yii2, pjax

I can't create a `Pjax` form inside an active form. What I've found is that when I put the `Pjax` inside an active form it doesn't work (it submits the entire page) but when I put it outside the active form its works fine:

```
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => 'CouplePartnerForm',
        'action' => ['couple-partner/savecouplepartner'],
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
        'enableClientValidation' => true,

        'validateOnSubmit' => true,
    ]);
?>

<div class="row">
                    <?php Pjax::begin([]); ?>
  <?= Html::beginForm(['couple-partner/form-submission'], 'post', ['data-pjax' => '0', 'class' => 'form-inline']); ?>
<?= Html::input('text', 'string', Yii::$app->request->post('string'), ['class' => 'form-control']) ?>
<?= Html::submitButton('Hash String', ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-primary', 'name' => 'hash-button']) ?>
 <?= Html::endForm() ?>
                    <h3><?= isset($stringHash) ?$stringHash :"" ?></h3>
       <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

So what is the problem here?

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly by using pjax inside an active form? It could have another way to achieve what you want.

Comment: i'm creating a registration page and user can update his profile pic so i need to upload image (like profile pic). but i wont do this with ajax to prevent the submission of all parameters.

Comment: I think you should have your registration page where user will upload the profile pic,  and you should add an edit button (oder icon) in the profile page who will open another form to update the profile pic. You should not do it in the same form.

Comment: it can not be done in another way ?...The company request is to doing it like i said :( ...